# C macro that creates an NSString variable with the variable name as the content of the string

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

Despite the fact that this is not good coding practice, I want a macro that should work like the following:

```
CREATE_STRING(fooBar)
```

And it should create the following code:

```
NSString *fooBar = @"fooBar";
```

My macro looks like this:

```
#define CREATE_STRING(varName) NSString *varName = @"varName";
```

But now I get the following

```
NSString *fooBar = @"varName";
```

It seems to be such an easy problem to solve and I have already checked the documentation [from IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/numnum.htm) but I just can't seem to get the `varName` into the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how to do it

```
#define CREATE_STRING(varName) NSString *varName = @"" #varName
```

It takes advantage of the fact that two string constants one after the other get concatenated by the compiler.

Comment: Did ANYBODY actually try my solution before downvoting?

Comment: How is this different to @H2CO3's answer?

Comment: It's different in that it concatenates two strings, not just inserts the C-stringified name after the '@'.

Comment: @H2CO3 He could have commented on your answer and you could have corrected it, couldn't you?

Comment: I actually tried to do so, but as you can see from his comment's, he is being ignorant...

Comment: @H2CO3 I was talking about JeremyP helping to modify *your* answer - I think you are getting your wires crossed...

Comment: @trojanfoe @H2CO3 When I posted my answer,  I adidn't believe the straight `@#varName` would work, because in olden days it didn't.  However, I have just tried it with the current clang compiler and now it does.  It was not me, by the way, that downvoted H2CO3's answer.  I always post comments when I down vote.

Comment: Thanks for all who helped clarifying that I was right. And then sorry @JeremyP for accusing you of downvoting.

Comment: ok I will try this, I find it very weird that the #varName has to be outside the @""...

Comment: @Besi: Actually the "" bit isn't needed.  See H2CO3's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
#define CREATE_STRING(varName) NSString *varName = @#varName
```

instead. (also note that you don't need the trailing semicolon in order to be able to "call" your macro as a C-like function.)

Comment: [...]Untitled.m:7:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'foo'; did you mean 'for'?
                NSString *mary = CREATE_STRING(foo);
                                               ^
Untitled.m:3:42: note: expanded from macro 'CREATE_STRING'
#define CREATE_STRING(varName) NSString *varName = @#varName
                                         ^
2 errors generated.

Comment: Did you call it as CREATE_STRING(foo); (with a semicolon at the end when calling)? If not, try to do so. The error is NOT at the point the macro is used.

Comment: I just swapped your macro definition for mine to get that error, yours can't work. You can only stringify macros in the preprocessor, so the approach I used in my answer is needed to convert the bare characters into a macro before it gets stringified.

Comment: "You can only stringify macros in the preprocessor" <- nope. Arguments can be stringified as well.

Comment: NSString *foo = CREATE_STRING(foo); is what I did, it doesn't work. See, e.g. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: I just compiled this one successfully:

#define CREATE_STRING(varName) const char *varName = #varName

int main()
{
 CREATE_STRING(fooBar);
 printf("%s\n", fooBar);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen the difference between the two macros now.

Comment: Then why on Earth are you downvoting, seriously?

Comment: By the time I worked out that you were doing something different, my vote was locked in. I note that you've done a spite down vote, and withdraw from a now irrational conversation.

Comment: The downvote is not spite, btw. Your answer DOES NOT answer the OP's question. He wants to declare and initialize a variable with the name specified as the agument of the macro, and does not simply want to create an NSString from an arbitrary string.

Comment: In other words, `NSString *mary = CREATE_STRING(Mary had a little lamb);` is wrong. OP wants CREATE_STRING(MaryHadALittleLamb); to expand to `NSString *MaryHadALittleLamb = @"MaryHadALittleLamb";`

Comment: +1 I just have tested this answer and it is perfectly fine.  Until I tried it I thought `@#varName` would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Graham Lee:  I just did a trivial edit on the answer so your down vote is no longer locked.